# Webhook Messagecard Connector Posts Distorting Image

Tags: json, base64, microsoft-teams, webhooks

I am trying to send a message to a teams channel using a webhook. I need this to include an image. The message sends successfully using **activityImage**, however the image gets rounded every time/is distorted. I would like it to just post the image in the dimensions it exists ideally (all are small images).

It doesn't seem like it's an issue with the base64 encoding so I'm guessing there's a syntax issue. I have not been able to find a thread where anyone else is having this problem where their images are rounded. I've tried using messagecard params **image**, **images**, and **heroImage** but none of these will even post the image to teams successfully.

**The Messagecard:**    `{"@type":"MessageCard","@context":"https://schema.org/extensions","summary":"summary","themeColor":"2e8b57","title":"Daily Scrum","sections":[{"activityImage": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAIAAAD91JpzAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAVSURBVBhXY3hvaf9WRYcBiN/KqAAAJ40FDwasafMAAAAASUVORK5CYII="}]}`

Note: encoding is done using https://www.base64-image.de/

Comment: We tried using the JSON provided and it renders as below. Could you please confirm if this is the case?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/neTHR.png

Comment: Yep correct. It makes all the images round like in your picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone running into a similar issue where you're unable to get messagecards posting your image in its proper resolution - I found that the **text** attribute can accomplish this. Using *image* or an array of *images* distorted the image resolution, and *ActivityImage* made the image round which was undesired. Using Base64 threw 500 errors depending on the size of the image. Below is what worked for me.

```
{
"@type": "MessageCard",
"@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
"summary": "summary",
"themeColor": "2e8b57",
"title": "Daily Scrum 11/6/2022",
"text": "![](https://somewebsite.com/the_image.jpg)"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is By design behaviour. `ActivityImage` is always rendered as avatar style in a circle.

Comment: Do you have a json solution that would produce the results I'm trying to achieve of the image being posted in its actual resolution? I have tried using image, image inside an images array, and heroimage with no luck - thanks

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be a bit late to the party, but default `activityImageType` is "avatar", hence the circle.  Have you tried in the JSON to explicitly use: `"activityImageType":"article"`?